# Flutter - Enable scroll only if content height is greater than screen height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am taking ListView() or SingleChildScrollView() in body widget by default. So it is scrolling the content if it is less content. I want to scroll enable only if content is greater than screen height. If content height is less than screen height, need to disable scroll.

```
double? physicalSizeScreenHeight =
  ui.window.physicalSize.height / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;

physics: physicalSizeScreenHeight <= 700 
? AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

It is working for some devices and not working for some devices depends on screen width and height and also depends on resolution.

Without checking any condition at "physics" for always or never and allow to AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), then depends on conent height, need to enable/disable scroll.

Any suggestions would be helpful to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, one of the (many) differences between `SingleChildScrollView` wrapping a `Column`, vs directly using a `ListView`, is the the former will only scroll if there are too many items in the `Column`.

If that's not what you are seeing, you might have other layout issues.

Try this simple layout `SingleChildScrollView` > `Column` > `Text('Hi')` and verify that it won't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

try to use it

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context);
final apparentSize = size.size.height - size.padding.bottom - size.padding.top
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your content exceeds the screensize using this,

`if (_scrollController.position.extentInside != _scrollController.position.extentTotal) { // .. your code here }`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).